# How To Wrap String in PHP with html tag

Tags: php

this is my first questions in stack overflow.
i want build search result in php.
i have code like below:

```
<?php
$kw = $_GET['keyword'];
// database process store in $data
// then echo result
foreach ($data as $d){
        $title = get_the_title($d);

        echo str_replace($kw , "<span class='highlight-text'>".$kw."</span>", $title)."<br/>";
    }
?>
```

but why i cant get the result with it?

thank you

Comment: If you can include the result you are getting and the result you are after, it would help understand where the problem may be.

Comment: for example i typed "news" in search form.

then the result is:

1. Latest News about Covid
2. World News Today
3. The Best News This Months


i want wrap the "news" string with in html tag use str_replace but the result give the plain text only, without wrapped with html tag inside

Comment: If you type in News - does that work.  It sounds like a problem with being case sensitive.

Comment: oh i see, you are answer right !!!

thank you dude.

i just realize that function str_replace() is case sensitive,
now i use str_ireplace() and work like charm...
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php